# Powershell change all file extsions in folder

Tags: 2013, powershell, sharepoint-on-prem

I need to change `~500 .html` files to `.aspx` however I do not know how to do so through `Powershell` and I have not seen any other feasible way to do so.

Folder location:

> \ \site\subsite\subsite\subsite\Shared%20Documents\schemas\Tables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to the folder location in Powershell and run this command:

```
Get-ChildItem *.html | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name -replace '\.html','.aspx' }
```